# Install pyUSB 0.4.3 on OSX Lion 10.7.3

Tags: python, macos, usb, osx-lion, pyusb

I'm trying to install pyusb 0.4.3 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 running Xcode 4.3 (the new Mac App Store .app with command line tools installed). 
When I try to "python setup.py install" I get this long list of error ending with "error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1":
http://pastebin.com/R8id7Qf7

pyUSB 1.0alpha2 installs fine.

Any ideas? I'm a bit of Unix noob so please explain accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have libusb installed.

Try here: http://www.anyma.ch/blogs/research/2011/08/13/libusb-for-macosx-lion-10-7/

And read the comments, there's an update in that section.

BTW,

Have you tried using:

```
sudo easy_install pyusb
```

or:

```
sudo pip install pyusb
```

easy_install comes with Lion, but not pip, you can install it:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 2):

You should install `libusb`. Personnaly I used `port` :

```
port install libusb
```

Comment: Worked for me! I used `brew` instead of `port`.