# pyusb on macOSX 10.11 step by step

Tags: python, macos, pyusb

Can anybody take my hand and guides me through installation of pyusb on my Mac, step by step ?
I have a fresh installed osx 10.11.6 (which comes already with python).
What I tried until now (nothing more, nothing less) is to install latest version of pyusb (v1.0.0) and stucked like this

```
xxx-MB:~ xxx$ sudo /Users/xxx/Downloads/pyusb-1.0.0/setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'usb' does not exist
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: silly question: do I need to move the folder pyusb-1.0.0 to any application folder before installation ?

Comment: Take a look at [this existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629333/install-pyusb-0-4-3-on-osx-lion-10-7-3). You will need to have `libusb` installed and you should try using `pip` to install the package.

Comment: Done. Just installed libusb, running setup.py install again, same message "error: package directory 'usb' does not exist"

Comment: btw. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

AHA

This did not work http://macappstore.org/libusb/

But this did [Install pyUSB 0.4.3 on OSX Lion 10.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629333/install-pyusb-0-4-3-on-osx-lion-10-7-3)

Used this approach

`sudo easy_install pip` and `sudo pip install pyusb`

Thanks